# DataWeave matching on dynamic regex in Mulesoft 3.9

Tags: mule, dataweave

Is there a way in dataweave in mule 3.9 to match against a regex stored in a variable?

The simplest example would be:

```xml
<!-- does not work -->
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Get value">
    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
payload matches flowVars.regex
]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
```

But that could be resolved using MEL `#[payload.matches(flowVars.regex)]` or simply
`#[regex(flowVars.regex)]`

A more elaborate example would be, there is a table with the following structure:

```
regex   | value
--------------------
^typeA$ | valuefor-A
^typeB$ | valuefor-B
```

Then we query this table and store it in a variable:

```sql
-- not real mule code
select regex, value
from tablewithregexdefinitions
into flowVars.RegexDefinitions
```

And then, we try and obtain the applying entries where the regex matches a `payload` field:

```xml
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Get value">
    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
(flowVars.RegexDefinitions filter (payload.field matches $.regex))[0].value default "fallback-value"
]]></dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hi there is no way to do that in DW 1.0 as when using the matches with a string transforms the string into a literal regex so it is not going to be interpreted. The only solution is to create a global mel function and call it from the DW code.