# Dataweave1 ( Mule 3 ) how do I use regular expression defined in properties file?

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

I have the following regex defined in a property file :

```
East.Europe=/\\b(?:Moscow|Russia|Elephant)\\b|[<>]/
```

and then in dataweave I am trying to check if payload contains any of these words or characters :

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java 
%var v1 = payload 
---
(write(v1, "application/json") contains p('East.Europe')) when (v1 != null) otherwise false
```

However code fails with error :

> com.mulesoft.weave.mule.exception.WeaveExecutionException: Exception while executing:
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'East.Europe' in value "${East.Europe}".

So in Mule 3 how do I read regular expression defined in properties file ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DataWeave matching on dynamic regex in Mulesoft 3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57497748/dataweave-matching-on-dynamic-regex-in-mulesoft-3-9)
This is the definitive answer on the topic.

Comment: thanks @aled so this unfortunately means this is not possible in dataweave 1 ...

Comment: The answer says is not possible with pure DataWeave 1.x but as a workaround you can call a MEL global function from a DataWeave script.